# Can't find a way to delete files that match a date pattern

Tags: linux, bash, synology

I'm trying to delete all files in a folder structure (recursively) except the youngest one for each month.

In other words.... only keep the first ones from each month in each folder.

On a Linux system (bash) ... ;-) (or even more precise on a Synology NAS)

May thanks for your help !
Alex

Comment: Define "youngest": The one with the most recent modification timestamp? In this case, I don't know what you are meaning by _date **pattern**_.

Answer (score -1):

**Please be careful! I take no responsibility!**

Try `find`:

Remove files which are older than 7 days:

```
find . -type f -ctime +7 -delete
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `-mtime` (modification time)? `-ctime` is, on Linux, the status change time. For instance, if the permission of the file change, the ctime is updated, although the file content stays the same.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes indeed... :) I would suggest that post owner should read the manual... :)